# Error when receiving a stream as response in gRPC

Tags: python, grpc

I am trying to implement a service where from a request from the client, I can receive a stream as a response.

The proto is the following

```
syntax = "proto3";


service VideoClassifier{

 rpc GetServerClassification(Image) returns (stream Result) {}

}


message Result{
    int64 id = 1;
    float x1 = 2;
    float x2 = 3;
    float y1 = 4;
    float y2 = 5; 
    string label = 6;
    float confidence = 7; 
   }


message Image{
    bytes image = 1;
    int32 width = 2;
    int32 heigth = 3;
    int32 id = 4;
}
```

The client is implementing the rpc as following:

```
def make_image(stub , f , w , h,  id_video ):
    frame= mec_ar_pb2.Image(image = f, width =  w , heigth  = h, id = id_video)
    r = stub.GetServerClassification(frame )
    print(type(r))
    for resp in r:
        print(resp)
    return frame
```

However, when printing the type of the response stream "r" I get the following type:

```
<class 'grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous'>
```

And the client is raising the following exception:

```
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Exception iterating responses: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1638824058.895157000","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:50051","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1064,"grpc_message":"Exception iterating responses: 'NoneType' object is not an iterator","grpc_status":2}"
>
```

Can you tell me more about what is happening? I think the problem is on the client-side. If you also need the server, just tell me and I can re-edit the question with the server.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, can you please add the server code for this function? It seems that you are not returning an `iter` from the server or something like this. I've tested a server returning `return iter([Result(id=x, x1=1, x2=2, y1=1,y2=2, label="", confidence=0.0) for x in [1]])` and it works.

Comment: I solved it really easily: it was actually the server that was continuing its execution without waiting for a function to return before giving an answer to the client.